# Reduce number to single digit using recurssion

Tags: php, recursion, numbers

```
$result = reduce($number);

function reduce($number) {
    $new_number = 0;
    if($number < 10) {
        return $number;
    }           

    $q = floor($number / 10 );
    $r = $number % 10;
    $new_number = $q + $r;

    if($new_number <= 9) {          
        return $new_number;         
    }
    else {
        reduce($new_number);
    }
}
```

I want to sum the numbers by its digits
For example, if i pass 10, it should return 1+0 = 1
This works if i pass 10
But not working when i pass 100.

Comment: You need to add `return` to the recursion call. It doesn't return the recursive call as you have it.

Comment: What do you mean with: "not working" ?

Comment: @kainaw There is a return statement in the if condition

Comment: @user_0 I passed 10 and i got the value 1. When i pass 100 i got nothing.

Comment: @agriz You are missing the return statement in the else after the if. See my answer below. That is where you need another return.

Comment: @agriz What do you want as results if you pass 99 ?

Comment: @Rizier123 99 = 18 = 9 I want to reduce it to single digit

Comment: @agriz Ah okay, well than I read your question wrong. ^ If you would have added this as example it would have been more clear. I though you just want the check sum. (updated my answer according to that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the word `return` near the end. It should look like this:

```
return reduce($new_number);
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you:

Just split your number into an array with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and then use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to add all digits together.

```
echo array_sum(str_split($number));
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want the checksum, but go down to a single digit, you also don't have to write that much code. Just call the function over and over again until the `array_sum()` is equal or less than 9.

```
function reduceToOneSingleDigit($result) {
    $result = str_split($result);
    while(array_sum($result) > 9) 
        return reduceToOneSingleDigit(array_sum($result));
    return array_sum($result);
}

echo reduceToOneSingleDigit(99);
```

Comment: And what if the sum of the digits is greater than 9? Do it again? You don't show how to keep doing it over and over until the sum is a single digit (as the question asks for).

Comment: Wait, this solution works, it's not recursive but it works, why the downvote? Actually this is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: @kainaw *And what if the sum of the digits is greater than 9?* doesn't matter, my solution works. *You don't show...*, Maybe because my solution doesn't use/needs recursion

Comment: Try your solution using `$number=99;`. The result should be 9. Is that what you get or do you get 18 (which is not 9).

Comment: @kainaw Why should be results be 9 with 99?!

Comment: I just tried 99 and it displays 18. It's simple : create a text file, name it sum.php, add <?php echo array_sum(str_split(99)); ?> and run it from you browser. The guy wants 1+0 = 1, so 9+9 = 18.

Comment: The question states that the result must be ONE DIGIT. Last I checked, 18 was two digits, not one digit. So, the 18 needs to be summed again to produce 9.

Comment: No, he wants to get single digits in order to get the sum of them. Ok, I guess we have some interpretation issues here.

Comment: You are completely missing the problem. The problem is that if he passes in 100, he doesn't get a return. The reason is that he is missing a return statement. This "solution" doesn't solve his problem and doesn't get the solution he is asking for. He wants any integer passed in to result in a single digit - it is stated right there in the title to the question.

Comment: Ok, ok, take it easy, pal.

Comment: @kainaw You were right, but I really couldn't tell it from OP's example with 10. I updated my answer now with a function, which just takes a few less code lines

Answer (score 2):

Just too much code, take a look at next one

```
print sum(125); // 8

// 5  12
// 2  1
// 1 + ~>0
function findSum($num)
{
    if($num == 0)
        return 0;
    return $num%10 + findSum(floor($num/10));   
}
```

so, even 100000 or 000001 will be  1, works just as U want, but it will have troubles if the paramater will be 0001000